# JMeter distributed server not sending results back to master server

Tags: jmeter, rmi

Issue: Remote Jmeter server is not reporting back the results to the master server.

Description:
Using a VMware server I have added several Ubuntu servers hosting various JMeter client/servers.  I have setup a very simple distributed Jmeter environment using one master and one remote slave.   I have a very simple test plan that uses FTP to transfer a single file to a third FTP server.

Jmeter Master: 192.168.19.219, Ubuntu 12.04, Java 1.7.0.51, Jmeter 2.11
Jmeter Slave: 192.168.19.201, Ubuntu 12.04, Java 1.7.0.51, Jmeter 2.11
FTP Server 192.168.19.211, Win2008 R2

Upon execution the test plan works correctly and the file gets uploaded and downloaded successfully to and from the FTP server.  Whats not working are the results.  Using wireshark I determined that no results were being sent back to the master server.  I then checked the jmeter-server.log and noticed some errors complaining about java.rmi.ConnectException.  Its trying to use 127.0.0.1 which is obviously not the correct address.  I read up and found to correct this you must set the param "java.rmi.server.hostname".

So on the slave server I edited the jmeter-server config file to the IP address of the slave server:
RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.19.201

The jmeter-server.log (attached) shows the java.rmi.server.hostname being picked up so I cannot figure out why further down in the jmeter-server.log its complaining about 127.0.0.1?  Where is 127.0.0.1 coming from?  Why is RMI not using 192.168.19.201?

Jmeter-server.log:

```
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading user properties from: /home/tester/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin/user.properties 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading system properties from: /home/tester/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin/system.properties 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Setting System property: java.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.19.201 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Setting System property: server_port=1099 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2014 The Apache Software Foundation 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Version 2.11 r1554548 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.7.0_51 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.vm.name=OpenJDK Server VM 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.name=Linux 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.arch=i386 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.version=3.2.0-60-generic 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: file.encoding=UTF-8 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Default Locale=English (United States) 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (United States) 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeterHome=/home/tester/apache-jmeter-2.11 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: user.dir  =/home/tester/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: PWD       =/home/tester/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: IP: 127.0.0.1 Name: LoadRunner2 FullName: localhost 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Starting backing engine on 1099 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Local IP address=192.168.19.201 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: IP address is a site-local address; this may cause problems with remote access.
Can be overridden by defining the system property 'java.rmi.server.hostname' - see jmeter-server script file 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Creating RMI registry (server.rmi.create=true) 
2014/04/24 14:22:02 INFO  - jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Bound to registry on port 1099 
2014/04/24 14:25:15 WARN  - jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Backing engine is null, ignoring reset 
2014/04/24 14:25:15 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2014/04/24 14:25:15 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2014/04/24 14:25:15 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2014/04/24 14:25:15 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2014/04/24 14:25:15 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2014/04/24 14:25:15 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2014/04/24 14:25:15 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2014/04/24 14:25:15 INFO  - jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Creating JMeter engine on host 192.168.19.201 base '.' 
2014/04/24 14:25:15 INFO  - jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Remote client host: 192.168.19.219 
2014/04/24 14:25:15 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Listeners will be started after enabling running version 
2014/04/24 14:25:15 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: To revert to the earlier behaviour, define jmeterengine.startlistenerslater=false 
2014/04/24 14:25:15 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='/home/tester/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin' 
2014/04/24 14:25:15 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='.' 
2014/04/24 14:25:15 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Applying properties {} 
2014/04/24 14:25:15 INFO  - jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Running test 
2014/04/24 14:25:15 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2014/04/24 14:25:15 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2014/04/24 14:25:15 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.' 
2014/04/24 14:25:15 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.' 
2014/04/24 14:25:16 ERROR - jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper: testStarted(host) java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:129)
at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteSampleListenerImpl_Stub.testStarted(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper.testStarted(RemoteListenerWrapper.java:85)
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:216)
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:336)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
... 8 more

2014/04/24 14:25:16 ERROR - jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper: testStarted(host) java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:129)
at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteSampleListenerImpl_Stub.testStarted(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper.testStarted(RemoteListenerWrapper.java:85)
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:216)
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:336)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
... 8 more

2014/04/24 14:25:16 ERROR - jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper: testStarted(host) java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:129)
at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteSampleListenerImpl_Stub.testStarted(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper.testStarted(RemoteListenerWrapper.java:85)
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:216)
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:336)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
... 8 more

2014/04/24 14:25:16 ERROR - jmeter.samplers.RemoteTestListenerWrapper:  java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:129)
at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteSampleListenerImpl_Stub.testStarted(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteTestListenerWrapper.testStarted(RemoteTestListenerWrapper.java:70)
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:216)
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:336)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
... 8 more

2014/04/24 14:25:16 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : FTP Thread Group 
2014/04/24 14:25:16 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group FTP Thread Group. 
2014/04/24 14:25:16 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2014/04/24 14:25:16 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 0 perThread 0.0 delayedStart=false 
2014/04/24 14:25:16 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: jmeterthread.startearlier=true (see jmeter.properties) 
2014/04/24 14:25:16 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Running PostProcessors in forward order 
2014/04/24 14:25:16 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2014/04/24 14:25:16 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2014/04/24 14:25:16 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: FTP Thread Group 1-1 
2014/04/24 14:25:16 ERROR - jmeter.threads.RemoteThreadsListenerWrapper:  java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:129)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.RemoteThreadsListenerImpl_Stub.threadStarted(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.RemoteThreadsListenerWrapper.threadStarted(RemoteThreadsListenerWrapper.java:52)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:597)
at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:961)
at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:946)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:566)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:554)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
... 12 more

2014/04/24 14:25:16 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times 
2014/04/24 14:25:16 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1 
2014/04/24 14:25:16 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true 
2014/04/24 14:25:16 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000 
2014/04/24 14:25:17 ERROR - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: sampleOccurred java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:129)
at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteSampleListenerImpl_Stub.processBatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender.sampleOccurred(BatchSampleSender.java:184)
at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender.sampleOccurred(DataStrippingSampleSender.java:92)
at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper.sampleOccurred(RemoteListenerWrapper.java:104)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.ListenerNotifier.notifyListeners(ListenerNotifier.java:84)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.notifyListeners(JMeterThread.java:783)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:443)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
... 12 more

2014/04/24 14:25:17 ERROR - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: sampleOccurred java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:129)
at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteSampleListenerImpl_Stub.processBatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender.sampleOccurred(BatchSampleSender.java:184)
at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender.sampleOccurred(DataStrippingSampleSender.java:92)
at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper.sampleOccurred(RemoteListenerWrapper.java:104)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.ListenerNotifier.notifyListeners(ListenerNotifier.java:84)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.notifyListeners(JMeterThread.java:783)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:443)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
... 12 more
```

Answer (score 15):

I got the same error as well. The fix is as follows.

While starting the client start with the following.

Jmeter Master:

./jmeter-server -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.19.219

Jmeter Slave:

./jmeter -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.19.201

Both client and server establishes connection to other. If unspecified the Slave sends local 127.0.1.1 to the Master. Master fails to open a connection to that ip and port, causing the error.

Comment: Just to add, all I had to do was o nthe "client" side run `./jmeter -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=[my ip address]`, and it was golden. This usually happens to me when I have more than one NIC (virtual or physical) - seems jMeter gloms to the WRONG NIC for incomming,and reports that to the "servers"

Comment: if you do not want to add `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname` every time you may try to change your `/etc/hosts` file so that it: 1) maps your hostname to your real public ip. 2) you might also want to map `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`

Answer (score 1):

Providing Hostname for both JMeter client and server solved the problem. This is explained on Apache JMeter user manual page but with different intention under [Tips section](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html).

You can start JMeter server with option "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=" on command line and same required for client.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why this isn't clearly documented but, on the client side you need to allow and/or define the *client*.rmi.localport

```
# Parameter that controls the RMI port used by the RemoteSampleListenerImpl
# Default value is 0 which means port is randomly assigned
#client.rmi.localport=0
```

http://gerardnico.com/wiki/jmeter/remote

So for the client

```
jmeter -n -t sometest.jmx -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=clientpublicip -Dclient.rmi.localport=4001 -Rremoteip1,remoteip2 -Gmyproperty=123 -l results.jtl
```

Comment: Thank you for linking to documentation that is 1000% clearer than the official JMeter one.